# How can I keep the radio button as checked after using it?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have on my webpage 6 radiobuttons. And when you click on one of the buttons, the overview will shown. But the chosen radio button isn't checked. You see that the button is shown as checked for a while. But than as the other ones it will be unchecked again.

How can I keep it checked?

The view:

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" >
        <% using (Html.BeginForm("Overige_Statistieken", "Hitdossier", 

        FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmStatistieken" })) %>
            <% { %>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="hitlijst_editie">Selecteer overzicht:</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <%= Html.RadioButton("Overzicht", "1", new
                            {
                                @onclick = "document.getElementById('frmStatistieken').submit();"
                            }) %> Overzicht Alle Nummer 1 hits per week
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <%= Html.RadioButton("Overzicht", "2", new
                            {
                                @onclick = "document.getElementById('frmStatistieken').submit();"
                            })%> Overzicht Alle Tips van de week
                        </td>
                    </tr>
...
        </table>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div>
             <%= Html.Action("Overige_StatistiekenLijst", new { AID_Overzicht = ViewBag.ID_Overzicht })%> <br />   
        </div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

... and this is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Overige_Statistieken(string AID_Overzicht = "1")
{
    ViewBag.ID_Overzicht = AID_Overzicht;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Overige_Statistieken(FormCollection ACollection)
{
    string sID_Overzicht = ACollection["Overzicht"].ToString();
    return Overige_Statistieken(sID_Overzicht);
}

public ActionResult Overige_StatistiekenLijst(string AID_Overzicht)
{
    ViewBag.ID_Overzicht = AID_Overzicht;

    ReadOverigeStatistieken(AID_Overzicht);
    return View(_ListOverzichtModel);
}
```

Comment: " You see that the button is shown as checked for a while. But than as the other ones it will be unchecked again." Is it shown as checked when you click it? Does it perhaps become unchecked when you submit the form and the page refreshes? What exactly occurs on the page when the button becomes unchecked?

Comment: All radio buttons have it's own overview. That works fine. But it is only view of the radio buttons that's wrong. All buttons are unchecked and stay unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an overload method that will allow you to set the initial state of the radio button, using the `isChecked` parameter (third argument).

```
<%= Html.RadioButton("Overzicht", "1",  (int)ViewBag.ID_Overzicht==1,  new
      {
          @onclick = "document.getElementById('frmStatistieken').submit();"
      }) %>
```

The following was added to your code. Do that same thing to all your radio buttons paying attention to the value (i.e. 1) you will check against.

```
ViewBag.ID_Overzicht==1
```

Comment: It looks okay. But I get the following message: Error 2 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<dynamic>' has no applicable method named 'RadioButton' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.

Comment: That was the problem. You had to convert the dynamic value into int or string.